# How to specify the numbers of characters for teaser for views block?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I know we can specify the specify limit for the teaser by going to content type -> manage display -> teasers. I have made the views block for teasers and I want to display only few lines for that content in particular views block and do not want to affect the stand treasure setting. So, is there any setting in Views which specify the teasers limit for the particular Views block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the view settings for the field, click on *Rewrite results. Select * Trim this field to a maximum length* and enter a value for the maximum allowed length.